# Add properties to project in Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to add some properties to a project, which is configured with custom plugin.

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.properties.put("my_property", "123)
        println(project.properties.get("my_property"))
    }
}
```

I see null in output. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how extra properties should be set:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.ext.my_property = 123
        println(project.my_property)
    }
}
```

And [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) You can find the whole section on how properties work with gradle.